# Tab is not working properly in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, tabs

In the below image

[image]

when i am using tab button from password input box ,

[image]

1st its going to tokencode input box after that if i am using tab button again it should go to cancel but its going to image which is there in the right side.
I am facing this issue only in Internet Explorer. please suggest me what to do?

Comment: Have you tried using the `tabIndex` attribute for the input tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the order of your tabbed elements with `tabindex` like this:

```
Field 1 (first tab selection):
<input type="text" name="field1" tabindex="1" /><br />
Field 2 (third tab selection):
<input type="text" name="field2" tabindex="3" /><br /> 
Field 3 (second tab selection):
<input type="text" name="field3" tabindex="2" /><br />
```

Comment: why not? http://caniuse.com/#search=tabindex 
it's supported from IE7. You have to add a tabindex to your image too

Comment: tabindex for image will be in negative value ?

Comment: when you give a negative tabindex, your element will be focusable but not reachabe through the keyboard! If it's that what you want you can do it!